# Return error from query before finishing it

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, return

I have following mysql script:

```
start transaction;
set autocommit = 0;
call RollbackRemove(1, 10);
call RollbackRemove(2, 5000);
commit;
```

and a procedure:

```
create procedure RollbackRemove(a INT, b NUMERIC(8, 0))
begin
    declare ret bool;
    select Remove(a, b) into ret;
    if not ret then
        rollback;
    end if;
end //
```

It tries to remove certain amount from each item, and if one remove fails, the transaction is rollbacked (inside procedure). However, I have noticed that even after calling rollback the script continues execution but that is not desired. Also I would like to be able to report an error (this will be called from php). I have been searching for mechanism that would end script sooner, something like `return` in other languages, but haven't found anything. What should I use in such situation?

Comment: You could use [exit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).

Comment: perhaps this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1275431/650405 ? ugly as ...

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yes this is all MySQL, only there is a redefined delimiter to // for procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) to raise an error.

Comment: does this stop the script?

Comment: if you raise an error, it terminates the procedure. If you raise a warning, no.

Comment: Thank you for fast reaction, the solution was to put `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'` under rollback in procedure, this will leave database in state before transaction and ends the script while also generating error, just what I needed.