# Disallow inserting text values into integer columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I accidentally tried to insert 'asdf' into an integer column. It worked (put 0 in the column), and gave this warning:

> Incorrect integer value: 'asdf' for
>   column 'Author' at row 1

How can I cause similar insertions to fail instead of merely issuing a warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of MySQL 5.0, there is an option `sql_mode` you can set, either in the `my.cnf` or during startup (`--sql-mode='<option>'`) or during a running session. When you set it to

```
sql_mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES
```

mysql will not issue a warning and insert the wrong value anyways, but it will refuse your statement with an error.

[See also in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables)

---

**Example:**

```
mysql> create table asdf (id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into asdf value ('Hello');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.38 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                   |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: 'Hello' for column 'id' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from asdf;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> set SESSION sql_mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into asdf value ('Hello');
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 'Hello' for column 'id' at row 1
mysql>
```

Comment: +1 for the detailed example before and after setting the option.

Comment: Say ... how exactly should I edit the my.ini setting?

I've tried adding sql_mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES" under the [mysqld] section, but it didn't have the desired effect.

Comment: I just checked. When i added `sql_mode = "STRICT_ALL_TABLES"` to my my.cnf, also in the `[mysqld]` section, it worked as I described. Are you sure, mysql loads the correct .ini ? Check with `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;` after restarting

Comment: Weird. When I'm connected via sqlyog, I manage to insert the entry. When I try the command line client I don't (as it should be).

Comment: does mysqlyog disable this setting by default? I don't have any experience with it, though

Answer (score 1):

Simply throw an error by using raiseerror().
It is used like an exception handling's "throw" keyword which raises an error on certain pattern

```
SELECT 
case WHEN colname<>IsString(@columnName) 
THEN raiseerror() 
ELSE expression2 
END AS size 
FROM `mytab`
```

Now create a user defined function IsString() in my case which will return boolean value for checking string. If input value is string it will raise an error.

[Check this thread to raise error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/raise-error-within-mysql-function)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. I'd like the mysql engine to throw this error when I try to insert bad data.