# How to throw an error in MySql procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, throw, stored-functions

What is the mechanism to force the MySQL to throw an error within the stored procedure?

I have a procedure which call s another function:

```
PREPARE my_cmd FROM @jobcommand;
EXECUTE my_cmd;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE my_cmd;
```

the job command is:

```
jobq.exec("Select 1;wfdlk# to simulatte an error");
```

then:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE jobq.`exec`(jobID VARCHAR(128),cmd TEXT)
BEGIN
DECLARE result INT DEFAULT 0;  
SELECT sys_exec( CONCAT('echo ',cmd,' |  base64 -d > ', '/tmp/jobq.',jobID,'.sh ; bash /tmp/jobq.',jobID,'.sh &> /tmp/jobq.',jobID)) INTO result; 
IF result>0 THEN 
# call raise_mysql_error(result); 
END IF;
END;
```

My jobq.`exec` is always succeeding.
Are there way to rise an error?
How to implement raise_mysql_error function??

I am using MySQL 5.5.8

Comment: related :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/raise-error-within-mysql-function

Comment: also read this chapter http://www.docstoc.com/docs/687360/Error-Handling-In-Stored-Procedure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is: use the [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) keyword.

Comment: Thank you! DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET err= 1 exactly that what I need!!!

Answer (score 7):

You may use following stored procedure to emulate error-throwing:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `raise`(`errno` BIGINT UNSIGNED, `message` VARCHAR(256))
BEGIN
SIGNAL SQLSTATE
    'ERR0R'
SET
    MESSAGE_TEXT = `message`,
    MYSQL_ERRNO = `errno`;
END
```

Example:

```
CALL `raise`(1356, 'My Error Message');
```