# Non editable field in database

Tags: database, postgresql

Sorry for this lame question, but I really am a database newbie:

I want to store the date when I create a certain field on the database. Is there any attribute I can add to that date field so that it cannot be modified? I just want the date field to have the date when a field is created on never want to edit it.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Thanks.

Comment: Which Database you are talking about? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: @vs dev: I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to actually do this; however, if you want to make this occur you would perform a trigger on update for that specific table.field and throw a [DBMS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/raise-error-within-mysql-function).  There might be a more elegant way to do this; but this is all I can think of to protect a specific value once it has been written.

Comment: so basically, what you are saying is to create the field with a DEFAULT for current_timestamp and never edit the field again right?

Comment: Well it could be a default value; but you could also set it on INSERT.  Creating a trigger for ONLY update will ensure that the field will not be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think PostgreSQL supports column level permissions. Check this : [PostgreSQL 8.4 Feature List](http://www.postgresql.org/about/press/features84.html)