# Alternative to block a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called 'messages' (INNODB) where the user can insert their own posts.
I want to put a limitation. In my php script when the table gets to 10 records, you can not add more. The logic of the program is more or less as follows.

Step 1. I run a query to count the lines that are in the table.

Step 2. Recovered that value, I decide whether to insert a new post.

My difficulty is in properly managing the possibility of two user who do the same thing simultaneously. If the user A is in step 1 while user B has just finished entering the tenth post, user A will include the eleventh.

How to avoid it?

Comment: could you post some of your php code pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to allow you to change your threshold value for the table, you can use a trigger. Because MySQL triggers don't have a "prevent `INSERT`" option, you need a value in your table set to `NOT NULL`. The trigger can then set the inserted value for that column to `NULL` which will prevent the `INSERT` if your condition check fails.

A trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER block_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON table_name 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN   
  DECLARE count INT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM table_name INTO count;
  IF count >= 10 
  THEN
    SET NEW.non_nullable_value = NULL;   
  END IF; 
END;
```

would fail if you inserted an 11th row, like this:

```
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'non_nullable_value' cannot be null
```

You may wish to set the non-nullable column's name to something that represents its use. You could improve this by having the trigger pull the limit value from a configuration table.

#### Update

To avoid having to use the non-nullable columns, you could alternatively create an error procedure, and `CALL` it from your trigger - similar to the [example in the "Emulating Check Constraints" section of this page](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers) - they're referencing Oracle databases, where a check constraint achieves what you want, but MySQL doesn't support them.

The "error procedure" in the example performs an `INSERT` of a duplicate row into an error table, causing a unique key error and stops the parent transaction also.

#### Update 2

As pointed out in the comment below, multiple simultaneous transactions may get round the checks - you'll have to use `LOCK TABLES <name> WRITE` in order to ensure that they can't.

Comment: The trigger solution is handy but is affected by race conditions.

Comment: The race conditions can be solved by proper use of locking. It's a shame MySQL lacks check constraints, but it means that using triggers is the only real workaround.

Answer (score 4):

You can create `CHAR(1)` `NOT NULL` field and cover it with `UNIQUE INDEX`. This will prevent of inserting  more than 10 rows.

Other solution that could work would be to create `BEFORE INSERT` trigger that checks number of rows and raises error if there are more than 10 ([look here for sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/raise-error-within-mysql-function)) (but in this case you can fail with condition races).

Comment: @Martin: it is a **char** field with length `1`. So it will contain `0..9` values (supposing you'll never try to write non-digits there) ;-)

Comment: It's the bracketed part of your comment I'm referring to. Could a check constraint enforce that (in MySQL)?

Comment: @Martin: uhm, no. Handling of possible values is completely a programmer's work here. And we're supposing that a developer will use `0..9` values. As you know there are no (?) "real" check constraints in mysql (like oracle has, for example), so I cannot think of any "correct" solution.

Comment: The `BEFORE INSERT` trigger (used with locking) is the only real solution here - the index method only works for a value of 10, and while it answers this specific question, it gives you a solution that can't be altered - if they change the requirements to say, 15 records, you'd then have to go with the trigger method *anyway* - it's much more maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

2/ You can also lock the MySQL table.

- execute : LOCK TABLES my_table
- Then do your business rules.
- execute : UNLOCK TABLES

This also ensure that each action is sequentially executed. (but you have to deal with performance overhead)

Hope this could be useful.

**Updated since the comments below : transaction don't work in this case**

*1/ You are using InnoDB, you can also use database transaction*

- *Open transaction*
- *Then do your business rules.*
- *Commit or rollback your transaction*

*This will ensure that each action are executed one after another.*

Comment: For resolving concurrency.

@trickwallett said : _My difficulty is in properly managing the possibility of two user who do the same thing simultaneously. If the user A is in step 1 while user B has just finished entering the tenth post, user A will include the eleventh.

How to avoid it?_

Comment: I think the point that @zerkms is making is that the transaction element is not itself actually helping, it's the `LOCK TABLES` that prevents the concurrent (erroneous) `INSERT` succeeding. Even if both operations happen in their own transaction, both will be able to be committed without errors, leaving you with over 10 rows. **You are however bang on with the `LOCK TABLES` suggestion**

Comment: Thx for explanation, tough that 'read' was also locked during transaction with InnoDB. (Actually i'm using the LOCK TABLES trick to emulate sequence for pk)