# return keyword in mysql stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql - How to quit/exit from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260157/mysql-how-to-quit-exit-from-stored-procedure)

Is there something equivelant to php's, c++, c, java, whatever **return** statement?

can i do something like

```
IF @numRows >= 1 THEN
  RETURN
END IF;
```

in mysql stored procedures???

Comment: procedures return values all the time. is there something special about what you want to get from the proc?

Comment: I just want to end it, so it wont execute commands that are not necessary.

Comment: @Paolo Falabella, Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Sp:BEGIN
    IF @numRows >= 1 THEN
        LEAVE Sp;
    END IF;

END$$
```

Comment: It was already solved by Paolo Falabella, but he wouldn't post it as an answer. 
TY.