# Exit mother Mysql Stored Procedure from Child Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

```
mother_sotred_proc()
begin
   CALL child_sotred_proc();
end;
--------------------------

child_sotred_proc()
begin
   # i want to exit from here in such way so that mother_sotred_proc stop working or exist;
end;
```

The motto is that if any exception found in child SP then immediately controller should stop working totally and will exit from mother SP and will throw a message.

Comment: [Try this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260157/mysql-how-to-quit-exit-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: sorry i have already seen it. And it will not the thing i want.