# How to throw SQLException in stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How can I throw exception in a stored procedure 
For example:

```
@temp int =0

As 
BEGIN
SELECT @int = COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1
END

IF(@temp>0)
throw SQL Exception
```

P/S: not use return value

Comment: mysql or mssql server or both?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[RAISERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql) for MSSQL Server. As @Marc Gravell: note the severity must be >= 16 for it to surface as a SqlException.

Read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/raise-error-within-mysql-function/2693423#2693423) for MySQL.

This [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/svetasmirnova/how-to-raise-error-in-your-mysql-application) also shows how to do it in MySQL (if <=6.0)

Comment: note the severity must be >= 16 for it to surface as a `SqlException`

Comment: @MarcGravell - I did not understood `severity >=16`?

Comment: @zameeramir sql server has the concept of  severity levels; only 16 and above are surfaced as exceptions...

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL there is no way to throw an exception in a stored procedure, but you can force an error by selecting from a non-existing table.
It helps if the tablename gives a description of the error.

**Example:**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE throw_exception (IN param1 INTEGER)
BEGIN
  DECLARE testvar INTEGER;
  SELECT testfield INTO testvar FROM atable WHERE id = param1 LIMIT 1;
  IF testfield IS NULL THEN
     /*throw the error here*/
     SELECT * FROM 
       error_testfield_in_atable_not_found_youve_entred_a_nonexisting_id_in_throw_exception;
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```