# MySQL Restrict Insert

Tags: mysql

How do I do the equivalent statement in MySQL? I want it if input is a certain value, don't insert the row.  In SQL SERVER, I can just say ROLLBACK.  What's the equivalent command in MySQL?  Thank you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_some_trigger
ON some_table
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  IF inserted.topic == 'test' THEN
    ROLLBACK
  ENDIF
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> The trigger cannot use statements that explicitly or implicitly begin
>   or end a transaction such as START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, or ROLLBACK.

So `ROLLBACK` won't work inside your trigger, but if the trigger raises an exception/error, it will prevent the insertion to succeed, so what you can do is raise an exception if your condition is met (one way is to call an undefined function).

For example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `db`.`before_insert` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `db`.`dummy_table`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF new.topic = 'test' THEN
        CALL func_1();
    END IF;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Assuming func_1 doesn't exist it will prevent your new record of being inserted.

Comment: Is this the only way?  Is it a good practice to just call a function that doesn't exist to make it fail?  If for some unfortunate reason, someone created a function with the same name, the trigger won't work anymore.

Comment: There is no throw or raise keyword in mysql, so that's one way, for the other ones look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/raise-error-within-mysql-function

Answer (score 1):

It's rollback in MySQL too.  Check out the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).