# Mysql constraint with conditions

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
PRODUCT_ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRICE DOUBLE NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(PRODUCT_ID)
);
```

I need a constraint which ensures the price is always greater then 0 if the NAME is NOT 'TestProduct'

I have been searching and not been able to find anything suitable

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL CHECK constraint alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807231/mysql-check-constraint-alternative)

Comment: check this 
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/check-constraint-does-not-work

this may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHECK constraint should do what you need. But in MySQL, it doesn't work - see this question:
[CHECK constraint in MySQL is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working)

Proposed workaround is to use trigger.

One more problem is that you can't do ROLLBACK in a trigger, so you have to use another workaround: call nonexisting procedure. See this question for details:
[MySQL Restrict Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148320/mysql-restrict-insert)

**Solution for your case**

From admin command prompt, execute:

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
```

Then from user command prompt:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER trig_price_check BEFORE INSERT ON PRODUCT
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.PRICE <= 0 AND NEW.NAME != 'TestProduct' THEN
CALL procedure_which_does_not_exist();
END IF;
END
$$

delimiter ;
```

Test:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO PRODUCT(NAME,PRICE) VALUES ('bread', 100), ('milk', 200);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.12 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO PRODUCT(NAME,PRICE) VALUES ('apple', 300), ('banana', 0);
ERROR 1305 (42000): PROCEDURE test.procedure_which_does_not_exist does not exist
mysql> SELECT * FROM PRODUCT;
+------------+-------+-------+
| PRODUCT_ID | PRICE | NAME  |
+------------+-------+-------+
|          1 |   100 | bread |
|          2 |   200 | milk  |
+------------+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

NOTE: for a complete solution, you may also want to add trigger for UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

you didnt specify what should happen when the value constraint is violated.

here's one way you could go:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger AFTER INSERT ON mytable
    IF (new.NAME <> 'TestProduct' AND new.PRICE <= 0)
        SET new.PRICE = default_price
    END IF
END;
```