# How do I write an SQL query that fails?

Tags: mysql, sql, testing, assertions

I need this query for testing exception handling, so I would prefer that the query is not schema dependent. I am looking for something like `SELECT 1;` but of course that doesn't fail.

I am using Java and MySQL but I hope to find answers that doesn't depend on programming languages and/or RDBMSs.

Comment: Why don't you take a moment to point out what's wrong with this question, before you downvote it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are tons of ways to make a query fail, like mispelling a field, or selecting from non existing tables. for example:

```
SELECT some_fake_field FROM table_that_doesnt_exists
```

Answer (score 6):

What about "SELECT 1/0" for starters?

Comment: well, that's annoying and IMHO not behavior I would consider correct as the default, but I'm not a MySQL guy :)  See @HeadofCatering comment below about the sql_mode setting (of course that disqualifies this answer as RDBMS-independent.)  There are also different type of exceptions that you may or many not want to test, syntax errors versus engine errors, for example - not knowing how/what you are testing, might it be possible those exceptions take a different path through your app?

Answer (score 5):

You could put an invalid token into the query

```
select doesnotexist.* from something_else
```

Or of course, what you should do is mock out the method and have it throw the exception during your test.

Answer (score 1):

One way to trigger a failure is to call a stored procedure with the wrong number of parameters. Another similar idea is to write an update/insert statement with the wrong number of arguments...

More ideas here:
[How to raise an error within a MySQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/how-to-raise-an-error-within-a-mysql-function)

Answer (score 0):

Any old syntax error will do... like an unterminated string

```
select 'bob
```

Answer (score 0):

To get 1/0 to raise an error in MySQL, you need to set sql_mode to ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO.

Try this:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO';
SELECT 1/0;
```

If this sql_mode isn't set, MySQL will return a NULL instead of an error.

You can check what your current settings are with the following:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```