# MySQL Equivalent of RAISERROR

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the MySQL equivalent of `RAISERROR` in SQL Server?

```
CREATE procedure GetallFiles()
as
begin
if not exists(select files.Files,Users.FirstName,Users.LastName,Users.EmailAddress from files,Users
where files.UserID = Users.UserID)
raiserror('cannot find files records',16,1)
end
begin

select files.Files,Users.firstname,Users.lastname,Users.EmailAddress from files,Users
where files.UserID = Users.UserID
end
return
```

Comment: When you say SQL do you mean SQL Server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to raise an error within a MySQL function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465727/how-to-raise-an-error-within-a-mysql-function)

Comment: yes sql server as in from sql server to mysql since I don't know what is the  similar to raiserror of sql server  for mysql since in mysql there is no such thing as raiserror('cannot find files records',16,1)

Comment: Did you research at all? Look at the link in my above comment...

Answer (score 4):

```
    SET @s = 'Unknown condition type  !';
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = @s;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.